# Excel VBA: Refer to objects by name when not knowing object type

Tags: vba, excel

I created a custom calendar form to insert a date into whether a cell on a sheet or a textbox on a form. When calling the form, I store the name of the target object (cell or textbox) in a cell on a sheet (named, say, targetObject). Then, I want the calendar form to insert the selected date into that object. My problem is that I can't find a way to refer to the target object.
The code would look something like:

(in the calling code:)

```
-if to insert date into a cell:
    [targetObject].Value="A1"
-if to insert date into a textbox:
    [targetObject].Value="MyForm.MyDate"
```

(then, in the Calendar Form):

```
Object("targetObject").Value = someDate
```

Everything I tried to refer to the object whose name is stored in [targetObject] failed. Can someone, please, have an idea?

Comment: Post a code where you call custom calendar form... Does 'targetObject' is named range?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the name of the control, then in the form code,

```
me.controls(controlName).Value = someValue
```

Comment: The thing is when I run the Calendar form I don't know beforehand if the object whose value I need to set (by passing the date selected in Calendar) is a control on another form or is a cell on a sheet. My question is just about that: how can I refer the object to update when I only know its name, be it a cell or a control.